# too far a stretch meaning?

Tags: meaning

> It does not seem too far a stretch, therefore, to include other unusual perceptions, such as visions, feelings of a felt presence, and additional sensations.

What does **too far a stretch** mean?

Comment: What has your research found.  What in particular can this forum help you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Too far a stretch"** comes from the Idiom;- **"Not by any stretch of the imagination"**
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-by-any-stretch-of-the-imagination
"even if you try, it is still difficult to accept: 
By no stretch of the imagination could you think of her as a real artist."

"It does not seem too far a stretch, therefore, to include other unusual perceptions, such as visions, feelings of a felt presence, and additional sensations."

> It means that it is easy to see (from what came before your quote) that you could conclude that including other unusual perceptions, such as visions, feelings of a felt presence, and additional sensations is par for the course.

Comment: Almost certainly correct. But does CED make the connection? I can't find OP's example 'It does not seem too far a stretch, therefore, to include other unusual perceptions, such as visions, feelings of a felt presence, and additional sensations.' there, though you don't indicate clearly that it's not, which is rather misleading.  // Google Ngrams would seem to show that 'not by any stretch of the imagination' has been around far longer.